# Deserializing multi-leveled JSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am completely new to the concept of JSON, and am having trouble figuring out how to deserialize a multi-leveled JSON statement using Gson.

This is what I'm trying to deserialize: `{"stat":"ok","pkey":{"id":"1234567890"}}`

First I tried doing using a hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Object> results = gson.fromJson(response, HashMap.class);
```

The result looked reasonable enough, but the second entry in the hashmap (the one that contained the actual id number) was a gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap, which I couldn't access.

Next I tried making a custom class to deserialize it into, but I can't seem to get it to work right...

Neither of these worked:

```
 class Results
{
    String stat;
    String[][] pkey;
}

 class Results
{
    String stat;
    String[] pkey;
}
```

The only examples I can find online have to do with deserializing simple, one level JSON, which looks easy. I just can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSONObject can easy deserializing multi-leveled JSON
This is Log "ok" and "1234567890" from your example

```
String json = "{\"stat\":\"ok\",\"pkey\":{\"id\":\"1234567890\"}}";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    Log.i("chauster", jsonObj.getString("stat"));
    Log.i("chauster", jsonObj.getJSONObject("pkey").getString("id"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is code for gson, you need to custom your class

```
public class Custom {

    private String stat;
    private IdClass pkey;

    public String getStat() {
             return stat;
    }
    public IdClass getPkey() {
             return pkey;
    }
    public Custom(String _stat, IdClass _pkey) {
        stat = _stat;
        pkey = _pkey;
    }

    public class IdClass {
        private String id;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        } 

        public IdClass(String _id){
            id = _id;
        }
    }
}

String json = "{\"stat\":\"ok\",\"pkey\":{\"id\":\"1234567890\"}}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Custom custom = gson.fromJson(json, Custom.class);
System.out.println(custom.getStat());
System.out.println(custom.getPkey().getId());
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Gson for this.

Comment: I add code for Gson that can log "ok" and "1234567890". But you need to create your custom Class for your json string